# Alterar idioma no banco de dados durante uma consulta

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

É possível alterar o idioma do banco de dados apenas durante a execução de uma query de inserção? Estou tendo problemas com conversão de datas devido ao formado delas, o Banco espera dd-mm-yyyy, mas na consulta está yyy-mm-dd.

Comment: Na verdade, você precisa converter antes, na linguagem que está utilizando para acessar o BD.

Comment: Olá Marcelo, eu tenho um insert já pronto, e este é muito grande e não dá pra ser criado novamente.

Comment: Então você quer a resposta fácil. Sem modificar nada realmente não sei responder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A maneira fácil é aplicando `CONVERT` e especificando como terceiro argumento o formato desejado. No seu caso, código 105:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 105)
```

Vai gerar algo como:

```
18-07-2014
```

Outros formatos: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx